# f:convertNumber doesn't throw conversion error on trailing alphabetic characters in decimal

Tags: jsf, converters, number-formatting

I am using `<f:convertNumber>` tag to convert a decimal input.

```
<f:convertNumber minFractionDigits="2" />
```

But it's accepting trailing alphabatic characters. For example, if I input `12345.1234AAA` it converts to `12345.123`. I would like it to throw a conversion error on that instead of trimming the alphabetic characters. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

This simply is the [standard behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324997/why-does-decimalformat-allow-characters-as-suffix) of [`java.text.NumberFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) as used by `<f:convertNumber>`: It trims all entries after the first not-allowed character (e.g. letters or decimal separators others than the ones defined in the input locale). Conversion only fails if the offending character is at the beginning.

I don't really like this behaviour because a user may not notice his mis-typed value got trimmed, resulting in unintended and (even worse) unnoticed auto-correction into a wrong value.

Interestingly enough, the specific number converters behave differently. Using `<f:converter converterId="javax.faces.Double" />` does not automatically handle non-numerical input, but fails conversion instead. However, the tag does not possess the additional attributes of convertNumber, such as minFractionDigits or currency symbols.

A different approach would be to write your own custom converter which extends the standard converter as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6670810/840977). You could then check the value for characters and directly abort further processing (throwing an according conversion exception) if you find any. If the value is already character-free you could call the standard behavior of the converter you derive from.

The drawback of both ways is that you loose the additional capabilities of `convertNumber`. You do not have attributes such as `minFractionDigits` or `currencySymbol` on  `<f:converter>`, so if you need this you'd have to find another way to pass in a parameter. Our implementation does not require any of these, so I haven't looked into this any further (we went for approach A), but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6933053/840977) presents an approach to do so.