# How to convert number using f:convertNumber on JSF form?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I have a input field which takes double can have only one of this pattern:

```
pattern="#,###,##0.00"
```

I've done this :

```
<h:inputText id="value"
             required="true"
             converterMessage="#{msg.invalidValue}"
             requiredMessage="#{msg.required}"
             value="#{technicalBean.value}">

    <f:convertNumber pattern="#,###,##0.00" />
</h:inputText>

<h:message  for="value"/>
```

But it's not working as I want. It accepts character, if the first input is number like as `8A` and converts number only.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit user to only type digits and `.` you can create javascript function and invoke it in `onkeypress` attribute or do this inline like this

```xml
<h:inputText id="value" required="true"
                 onkeypress="if ((event.which == 8) || (event.which == 46)) return true; if (event.which &lt; 48 || event.which &gt; 57) return false;"
                 converterMessage="#{msg.invalidValue}"
                 requiredMessage="#{msg.required}"
                 value="#{technicalBean.value}">
    <f:convertNumber  pattern="#,###,##0.00" />
</h:inputText>
<h:message  for="value" />
```

This will allow only digits, `.` and backspace (numbers are ASCII values for buttons).

If you are open for new framework, PrimeFaces got `<p:inputMask>` [component](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inputMask.xhtml) which you can use for this purpose.

Comment: I don't have problem to limit user but on key press not give me enough validation because user can copy and paste wrong data, thank you for answer.

Comment: about mask is very limited to user.

Comment: What you did is not validation but converter, if you want validation you should make validator or use JSR303 Bean Validation like `@Pattern` and after user presses key validate input.

Comment: i want to use pattern for view old data not for validation ,only i want to validate number.

Comment: I believe you have the same problem like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11253368/jsf-convertnumber-tag-issue-with-trailing-alphabatic-char) if you don't want to allow `double` value with alphabetic characters after digits.

Comment: thanks for you, this answer enhancement my logic and enough to me :)