# JSF Chaining Converters

Tags: spring, jsf, converters

According to this answer [multiple converters on single value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6670810/4413257) are not supported. So I tried to build chained converter by employing bean helper:

```
// Bean.java
public Converter chained(Converter... converters) {  return ...; } 

// view.xhtml
<p:inputText ... converter=#{bean.chained(aConverter, bConverter)} />
```

Unfortunatelly, this is not possible due of EL cast exception (proxy can not be cast to `Converter` nor to `Object`). This is probably caused by `SpringBeanFacesELResolver` registered in *faces-config.xml*.

Second attempt was try to build `@FacesConverter` from component attributes, however `UIComponent#getAttributes()` does not contain attributes where value is `@Component` injection.

```
<f:attribute name="converter_a" value="#{aConverter}" />
```

So the only way I can think of is to **provide in attribute converter id and try to find it** in "ChainingConverter" instance somehow.

Do you know how to find converter by id?

**UPDATE**

I've also tried to pass converter method as `MethodExpression`:

```
// Bean.java
public Converter chained(MethodExpression... expressions) {  return ...; } 

// view.xhtml
<p:inputText ... converter=#{bean.chained(aConverter.getAsString, bConverter.getAsString)} />
```

In this case `{ConverterClass} does not have the property 'getAsString'` (It seems that passing an expressions is possible only in composites with method-signature attributes).

**UPDATE**

I have ended with solution which builds converter in backing bean:

```
// Bean.java
public Converter getConverter() { return ...; }

// view.xthml
<p:inputText ... converter=#{bean.converter} />
```

Comment: Why do you need this? I've never had this requirement myself the recent years, nor seen it being asked before.

Comment: @Kukeltje It would be useful to compose converter from the existing ones e.g. String might be processed by multiple converters.

Comment: Same question... Why multiple converters after one another?

Comment: @Kukeltje I know I can write specific converter which will do what I want, but such a design is poor. Suppose you have input where you need to apply only "trim" conversion, another might require to apply "trim" + "encoding" conversion, etc. Why to write multiple converters each for specific case, when composition would solve all the cases?

Comment: I never told you to write a single converter, I wanted to know why you think you need multiple converters Are you sure trimming, encoding is not better executed in the model or business layer instead of the view?

Comment: @Kukeltje I was trying avoid to processing an input in model/business layer. I've ended with converter creation/composition in backing bean.

Comment: You don't 'process an input' in a business/model layer, you process a business value in the business/model layer. If you think you did the former, maybe your model got replicated in the controllers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301363/jpa-entity-as-jsf-bean

Comment: I guess you misinterpreted the error. EL does **not** support varargs in first place. Just create a method with two arguments.